# JSON dropdown implemetation in JSP, getting 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: java, jquery, json

Please help me with this JSP dropdown that I want to implement using JSON.

I am getting 500 error:
GET http://localhost:8080/ProjectManager/getEmployeesInProject.view?projectId=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is  the script that I am using:

Hi Guys, Please help me with this dropdown that I want to implement using JSON.

I am getting 500 error:
GET http://localhost:8080/ProjectManager/getEmployeesInProject.view?projectId=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

---

This is  the script that I am using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select#projectList').change(function(e){
       // Your event handler
       //alert(1);

        $.getJSON ("getEmployeesInProject.view", {projectId: $(this).val()}, 
                function(j) {
                    alert('j.length '+j.length);
                    var options = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("select#employeeList").html(options);
                });
    });


});

</script>
```

---

My JSP form is :

```
    <br />
    <br />




    <table width='670'>
        <tr>
            <td width='600'>Projects *</td>
            <td>
                <select id="projectList">
                    <c:forEach var="listProjects" items="${listProjects}"
                        varStatus="i">
                        <option value="${projectId[i.index]}">${listProjects}</option>
                    </c:forEach>


                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='600'>Descriptions*</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="taskDescription"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width='600'>Start Date of Task[dd-mm-yyyy]*</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="taskDescription"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width='600'>Due Date of Task[dd-mm-yyyy]*</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="taskDescription"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width='600'>Who should do this? *</td>
            <td><select id="employeeList">
                    <c:forEach var="listEmployee" items="${listEmployee}">
                        <option>${listEmployee}</option>
                    </c:forEach>


            </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td> <input type = "submit" value = "Add a task" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>





</form:form>
```

---

This is my controller part:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getEmployeesInProject.view")
    @Transactional

   public @ResponseBody List<Employee> fetchEmployeesInProject(@ModelAttribute("project") Project project, @RequestParam(value="projectId", required=true) int projectId, ModelMap modelMap){


    return assignTasksService.fetchEmployeesInProject(projectId);

   }
```

Comment: A 500 error means it's something in your controller. Step through the code and find the error

Comment: 500 error is a server internal error and i see no server side code here.. you have to add it ..

Comment: You also haven't tagged this with the server language you are using

Comment: @charlietfl, do you mean controller class code, then I have included that already, please hep

Comment: apologies, new in stack overflow question posting.I am using Java

Comment: so if that is java code....add a java tag to the question. jQuery has nothing to do with what happens on server

Comment: @charlietfi, just done with tagging to java

Comment: And the Application Server error?